# Logout link with image

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, logout

I have a html page which require users to login.
What will be the best format to use for the logout button? I was also considering using an image beside the word "Logout" (the link to logout) which will redirect them to the home page:index.html.

Comment: There is no best format. Use whatever you want to use that works.

Comment: logout word with title or image with alt+title, both are good options

Comment: Ok, could I please know how to go about using an image which says logout as a link to enable users logout?

Comment: It would be nice if I could get a sample code, either javascript or html, nothing fancy. Thanks

Comment: can you show what your login code looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok, could I please know how to go about using an image which says
>   logout as a link to enable users logout?

Use a regular HTML:
`<a href="logout.php"><img src="logoutImg.png"></a>`

Comment: Ok, that's what I had in mind. Thank You. One more thing, this will obviously mean I need to have a logout.ohp file with destroy session right?And how will I also link it to the home page (index.html)?

Comment: @KesienaSowho absolutly, and in the logout.php you can add header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/index.html' ) ; to redirect after the logout